# How do I extend /dev/sda9 or any hard-disk from ubuntu image file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

I have set up Ubuntu in orcl-vBox with 1 GB space in /var so while using the system it is filled up. I have 10 gb of allocated space from where i tried to create partition & map to /var .but the device /dev/sda9(extended partition) ,while unmounting generates devise busy error " as expected.

I rebooted the system from ubuntu image & copied the contents in /. The cfdsk screen looks like below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVYnw.png)

My ask is:

1. if i delete the /dev/sda9 mapped in /var using this cfdisk utility & then reboot from *.vdi (meaning vbox hdd) will the system work? am hesitating as i havent changed the /etc/fstab entries which should still show /dev/sda9 is mapped to /var.
2. I havent created any lvm purposefully for some POC, so without lvm what is the convenient & performance improved way to extend /var without any system reboot issue?

Comment: Since it's a virtual machine, you can always create a snapshot before experimenting and revert in case of failure?

Comment: yes agree, after doing some more research over internet, i reboot my system using image,them unmount var, remount in another directory of a disk.This somehow resolve the issue.